# Collections.shuffle multiple times in a row

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

dI got a little question about the Collections.shuffle() method.

Case:

I have 2 lists I need to shuffle, then union / merge them into one list, then shuffle the new complete list. I have used the shuffle method with the Random class - using system.nanoTime() as seed.

Code looks as below:

```
public List<PresentationArticle> shuffleUnionShuffleLists(List<PresentationArticle> list1, List<PresentationArticle> list2) {
    shuffleList(list1);
    shuffleList(list2);

    List<PresentationArticle> resultList = //merge/union the two lists

    shuffleList(resultList);

    return resultList;
}

public void shuffleList(List<PresentationArticle> articleList) {
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(articleList, new Random(seed));
}
```

My question is: Will this be a proper random shuffling of the lists, when the methods runs right after eachother, with a new Random object and a new (but almost identical) seed?

The method `shuffleUnionShuffleLists()` will be run approximately every 3 minutes.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @RowlandShaw This is Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason I can think of to shuffle the lists before merging. Randomising/shuffling something twice does not make them any more random.

> Will this be a proper random shuffling of the lists

Yes but you are doing too much.

Comment: Luckily for me, my company has awarded me with an assignment where its needed. I was missing some info aswell - where i only need a limited number of random elements from each list, that is then merged/sorted/reduced into the resultList.

Answer (score 2):

The default seed is based on nanoTime and a counter, so it is slightly more random than what you have.  Also there is no need to shuffle more than once.  Once it is randomized doing it more than once just takes longer.

So in your case, all you need to do is add the two list together and shuffle that using a `new Random()`, or reusing an old one.

```
public List<PresentationArticle> shuffleUnionShuffleLists(List<PresentationArticle> list1, List<PresentationArticle> list2) {
    List<PresentationArticle> list = new ArrayList<>(list1.size()+list2.size());
    list.addAll(list1);
    list.addAll(list2);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}
```

Also it is usually best not to modify arguments passed to you.

Comment: I need the shuffle on the 2 lists before they get added together - reason why aint that important. But if i get the same result of randomness from just using shuffle(list); then ill do that instead. Thanks for info about the shuffle method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't generally create a new Random object for every invocation. It doesn't make it "more random". Secondly, shuffling several times doesn't increase entropy either, so a single shuffle is all that is needed.

Comment: I was missing out some detail about the union/merge. It also reduces the 2 lists if there are "too many" elements in them. Lets say fx. list1 contains 10 elements (i only want 5, but i want a random 5 elements), and list 2 is 20 elements (and i only want 5 elements from that list, but i want a random 5 elements). Then i need to shuffle list1 and list2, before merging/sorting/reducing the lists into one list. This list i also want to be randomized, hence the 3rd shuffle.

Comment: So basicly, i can just create a Random object with an initial seed as a property in the class - and then use random.nextInt(); for each time i want to shuffle the lists?

Comment: @MartinHansen Yes, there's no need to use more than one Random object at all.